# "Unresolved reference:" errors with testCompile

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, spek

Currently, I'm getting `Unresolved reference: spek` and `Unresolved reference: test` with `testCompile / testRuntime`:

```
project(":core") {
        apply plugin: "kotlin"

        dependencies {
            // ... other dependencies
            testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion"
            testCompile "org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:$spekVersion"
            testRuntime "org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:$spekVersion"
            testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoVersion"
            testCompile "com.natpryce:hamkrest:$hamkrestVersion"
        }
    }
```

However, when I switch them with `compile / runtime`, I can run the tests successfully!

Here's my spek test:

```
package com.mysampleapp

import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.describe
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.it
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class DummySpec : Spek({
    describe("a dummy") {
        it("contains a number") {
            val dummy = Dummy(1)

            assertEquals(1, dummy.number)
        }
    }
})
```

Could someone please help me to debug this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause. My tests are inside my `Source Folder`.

To fix this, I moved my tests out, so `Source Folder` will not overlap with `Tests Source Folder`.

Comment: I thought you should have your main class in `src/main/kotlin/` and then your tests in 'src/test/kotlin'. Please confirm!

Answer (score 0):

`testCompile` is not supported by gradle 7.x and above.
Consider to working with `testImplementation`.